# will application_end be called when all users session end?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, global-asax

i have a smqll question,
will the application_end event in global.asax gets called when all users end there session?

was it like this in the past maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0 Topic:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

> The Application_Start and
> Application_End methods are special
> methods that do not represent
> HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls
> them once for the lifetime of the
> application domain, not for each
> HttpApplication instance.
>
> Application_End    Called once per
> lifetime of the application before the
> application is unloaded.

So it does not relate to when all user sessions have closed. It occurs when the application is unloaded from memory, i.e. as the result of a `web.config` or `global.asax` file change or ASP.NET recompilation, or, *I presume*, when the site is set to stopped from the web site management interface of IIS6.

Comment: I'd like to note that Application_End can also be called after application unload due to user's inactivity (parameter `idleTimeout` in application pool settings). So, Application_End can be emitted _after_ all users end their sessions.